# Problem parsing page from Wikipedia with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I have a very simple test script for fetching an article from Wikipedia and grabbing the first paragraph of the text which appears in the page (i.e. the `summary`).

Here it is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicia_faba" 
print url
source = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
print soup
summary = soup.find('p').getText()
print summary
```

I get nothing when parsing the `summary`, although the page is successfully fetched and correctly passed to `BeautifulSoup`.

This looks quite a simple problem, but I could not progress further. `BeautifulSoup` is full of tricks but unfortunately I am not privy of many of them!

Thanks in advance for any hints or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a few things in your code:

**Python 3.x:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request



url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicia_faba"
print(url)

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    source = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
# print(soup)
# summary = soup.find('<p>').getText()
# print(summary)

for para_tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    print (para_tag.text)
```

OUTPUT:

> Faba sativa Moench.
>
> Vicia faba, also known in the culinary sense as the broad bean, fava
>   bean, or faba bean is a species of flowering plant in the pea and bean
>   family Fabaceae. It is of uncertain origin[1]:160 and widely
>   cultivated as a crop for human consumption. It is also used as a cover
>   crop, the bell bean, which has smaller beans. Varieties with smaller,
>   harder seeds that are fed to horses or other animals are called field
>   bean, tic bean or tick bean. Horse bean, Vicia faba var. equina Pers.,
>   is a variety recognized as an accepted name.[2]
>
> Some people suffer from favism, a hemolytic response to the
>   consumption of broad beans, a condition linked to G6PDD. Otherwise the
>   beans, with the outer seed coat removed, can be eaten raw or cooked.
>   In young plants, the outer seed coat can be eaten, and in very young
>   plants, the seed pod can be eaten.
>
> Vicia faba is a stiffly erect plant 0.5 to 1.8 metres (1.6 to 5.9 ft)
>   tall, with stems that are square in cross-section. The leaves are 10
>   to 25 centimetres (3.9 to 9.8 in) long, pinnate with 2–7 leaflets, and
>   colored a distinct glaucous (Latin: glaucus) grey-green color. Unlike
>   most other vetches, the leaves do not have tendrils for climbing over
>   other vegetation.
>
> The flowers are 1 to 2.5 centimetres (0.39 to 0.98 in) long with five
>   petals; the standard petals are white, the wing petals are white with
>   a black spot (true black, not deep purple or blue as is the case in
>   many "black" colorings)[3] and the keel petals are white.
>   Crimson-flowered broad beans also exist, which were recently saved
>   from extinction.[4] The flowers have a strong sweet scent which is
>   attractive to bees and other pollinators.[5]

goes on ...

**EDIT:**

You need to understand the way that article is written, grab the outer-div, then the tag within that needs to be grabbed.

Something like:

```
container = soup.find("div",attrs={'class': 'mw-parser-output'})

paragraph = container.find("p")

for p in container.find_all("p"):
    if 'Vicia faba, ' in p.text or 'Some people suffer ' in p.text:
        print (p.text)
```

OUTPUT:

> Vicia faba, also known in the culinary sense as the broad bean, fava
>   bean, or faba bean is a species of flowering plant in the pea and bean
>   family Fabaceae. It is of uncertain origin[1]:160 and widely
>   cultivated as a crop for human consumption. It is also used as a cover
>   crop, the bell bean, which has smaller beans. Varieties with smaller,
>   harder seeds that are fed to horses or other animals are called field
>   bean, tic bean or tick bean. Horse bean, Vicia faba var. equina Pers.,
>   is a variety recognized as an accepted name.[2]
>
> Some people suffer from favism, a hemolytic response to the
>   consumption of broad beans, a condition linked to G6PDD. Otherwise the
>   beans, with the outer seed coat removed, can be eaten raw or cooked.
>   In young plants, the outer seed coat can be eaten, and in very young
>   plants, the seed pod can be eaten.

Comment: Thanks. But I need just the first two paragraphs, how can I get them from para_tag.text?

Comment: Probably better not to quote so much output in your answer, but +1 anyway

Comment: Your first solution works fine, and I have been able to get the paragraph of interest by using just a line counter. However, the edited answer is not generic, as the script is intended to be applicable to any page grabbed from Wikipedia.